# AuthorizationError on 'submit_for_settlement'=True Braintree python

Tags: python-3.x, payment-gateway, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-vault

I am using `sandbox` account credentials where my user has all the permissions still when I create a transaction it gives me `AuthorizationError`

Here is my code.

```
self.braintree_client.transaction.sale(
                {
                    "amount": charge["amount"],
                    "payment_method_token": "token_stored",
                    "merchant_account_id": merchant_id,
                    "options": {
                        "submit_for_settlement": True,
                    },
                }
            )
```

Everything works fine If I remove the `submit_for_settlement` but I want to settle the payment.

Does anyone have anyone have any idea  what I am doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that your user has the [Right](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/control-panel/users-roles/role-permissions#permission-submit-sales-for-settlement) to submit sales for settlement. Without this permission added to your User's Role, you'll get an authorization error.

More on [managing user roles and permissions here](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/control-panel/users-roles/managing-users-roles)

If you have any further questions or continue to encounter this error, [contact Support](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/help).